# IntegralUI-Web-Angular Issue while upgrading Angular Version

Tags: angular, treeview, upgrade

I am upgrading my Angular application from v9 to v14. Currently, I have made it stable on Angular v10. Now, I'm moving on to v11, and most of package issues are resolved.

I am using IntegralUI Web for Angular for treeview [v20.3](https://github.com/lidorsystems/integralui-web-angular)

While checking the issues on github repo, I found that I need to move on to [IntegralUI Web](https://github.com/lidorsystems/integralui-web). For free package, I found the [lite](https://www.lidorsystems.com/products/web/lite/) version.

I am not able to make it working, and getting import errors. I have also not found any working demo for angular v11.

I tried to make the code from quickstart application work in my application, but it is giving me errors.

The demo is taken from [here](https://www.lidorsystems.com/products/web/lite/).

My package.json contains following dependencies

```
{
    ...
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
    "integralui-web-lite": "github:lidorsystems/integralui-web-lite"
    ...
}
```

Can anyone help me with this or provide working code for angular v11 with integralui-web components?